# The pdo query for the full calendar event does not fire?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to select individual teacher's schedule to be displayed on the full calendar each time the drop down is selected.

And here is the jquery that I wrote :

```
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#teachermale").change(function(){
                  var str = "";
                   $("#teachermale option:selected").each(function(){
                      str += $(this).text() + "";  
                  });
              //$("#val").text(str);
                  console.log(str);
              changeDisplay(str);

               }).change();

      }); 
      function changeDisplay(str){
        console.log(str);
         $.ajax({
                 url:'find_event.php',
                 type:'POST',
                 data : '&str='+encodeURIComponent(str),
                 dataType:'text',
                 success: function(json) {
                    alert('The string has been passed');
                 },
                 error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText); 
                 }
              });

       } 
      </script>
```

HTML for the select box:

```
      <select id="teachermale" name="teachermale">
        <option selected disabled>Male Teachers</option>
        <option value="Mohamed Adil">Mohamed Adil</option>
        <option value="Sherif Reda">Sherif Reda</option> 
        <option value="Mohamed Shahban">Mohamed Shahban</option> 
        <option value="Abdullah al Haiti">Abdullah al Haiti</option>
        <option value="Salah">Salah</option>
        <option value="Ahmed Nabil">Ahmed Nabil</option>  
        <option value="Abdul Tawab">Abdul Tawab</option>
        <option value="Mahmoud Mahmoud">Mahmoud Mahmoud</option>  
        <option value="Ahmed Ghanim">Ahmed Ghanim</option>
      </select>
```

And here is the php for find_event.php

```
       <?php
            // List of events
            $json_array["title"]=$_POST["str"];
            $title =$json_array["title"];

            // connection to the database
            try{

                    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=******', '*****', '*******');
                } catch(Exception $e) {

                exit('Unable to connect to database.');
            }

             // Query that retrieves events
            $requete = "SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE `title`=?";
             // Execute the query
            $resultat = $pdo->query($requete) or die(print_r($pdo->errorInfo()));
             // sending the encoded result to success page
            $resultat->execute($title);

             $events = array();
             $dbEvents = $resultat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                foreach ($dbEvents as $event) {
                        $event['allDay'] = false;
                        $events[] = $event;
                }


             echo json_encode($events);

            ?>
```

The console writes the name of the teacher twice due to the console.log statement in the select jquery function and also in the function for the changeDisplay(). However, it seems that the query does not execute. Can someone assist me here.

Comment: AFAIK `execute()` expects array as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

First, you're mixing to functions - `query` and `execute` which both do the same - execute a query. And here you use `?` placeholder, but don't set value for it.

So, your proper code should be:

```
// Query that retrieves events
$requete = "SELECT * FROM `evenement` WHERE `title`=?";
// Prepare your query
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($requete);
if ($stmt) {
    // argument of execute is array, not single value
    if ($stmt->execute(array($title))) {
        $events = array();
        $dbEvents = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // more codes
        // ...
    } else {
        // check for error
        print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
    }
}
```